# Load webpage content into a div on page load and hide URL?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm calling a page (test.html, test.php etc.) through below method:

test.html

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $("#siteloader").html('<object data="test.html">');
</script>

<div id="siteloader"></div>​
```

Inspector output:

```
<div id="siteloader"><object data="test.html"></object></div>&#8203;
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#siteloader").html('<object data="test.html">');
</script>
```

Google chrome, Firebug (mozila) inspect output showing file name in source code. For example, `data="test.html"`

How can I hide this file destination (address, URL) from source code viewers?

Reason is I don't want they find out my test.html

Comment: You can't hide any attribute value from a source code inspector.

Comment: If you know any other alternate way to do that then please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Load the html serverside with include() in php is the only way to hide the url.

Comment: **Hmmm.. thank you for reply @seahorsepip!** Can you give me any example or reference website?

Comment: OMG, You're right Mr.@seahorsepip. Perfect.. I got the solution.. Thank you!